# users appRoleAssignments throwing error with filter resourceid eq

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I need to implement logic to remove appRoleAssignments of an user, but I have only user id and resourceId, I tried to use users appRoleAssignments graph API, but it requires .  is there any option to filter appRoleAssignments with userId and resourceId

Tried resourceId filter option for Get and Delete operation but both were throwing below error.
Reg: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users//appRoleAssignments?$filter=resourceId eq ''

{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-06-14T17:30:11",
            "request-id": "someid"
        }
    }
}

I do not want to get all the appRoleAssignments of an user using userId and perform delete operation with id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue on my side, to get the appRoleAssignment with resourceId successfully, please don't pass the `''` or `""`, just use the sample below.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<object-id>/appRoleAssignments?$filter=resourceId eq 90bf87ee-5d26-49bd-aeee-7532a8f32cc0
```

[image]

Then copy the `id` in the response, delete the appRoleAssignment like below, it works fine.

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<object-id>/appRoleAssignments/<id>
```

[image]

**Update:**

If you can also accept to use the powershell, you could use the script below, make sure you have installed the [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) module.

```
Connect-AzureAD
$userid = "<user object id>"
$resourceid = "<resource id>"

$id = (Get-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $userid -All $true | Where-Object {$_.ResourceId -eq $resourceid}).ObjectId
Remove-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $userid -AppRoleAssignmentId $id
```

Comment: Thank you Joy for providing option to get the id using resourceId filter, but it will become 2 step process to perform delete operation. It would be great if we have the same filter for Delete operation

Comment: @KrishnaAnumothu The `DELETE` action is not allowed to use the filter, https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqziS.png, to use the [MS Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), the `id` is needed.

Comment: @KrishnaAnumothu  If you can also accept to use the powershell, I can give you a solution, I think it is more convenient, see my update.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have to go with 2 calls is there is no option to delete without id.